# Explanation of a Diagram in Wikipedia

Tags: integration

In the following diagram ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Integral_of_positive_function.svg)), there are levels on $y$-axis by red lines. I didn't understand how the rectangles below these red line are drawn? Can one help me?

I am thinking the area of the rectangular regions as an approximation to area under the curve. but I failed to see how rectangles are drawn there? i.e. on what basis? (Like, as in Riemann integration, we draw rectangles by considering maximum and minimum values of function in the selected subintervals. what is going on here?)

---

**Integral of positive function**
[image]

Comment: Perhaps a link to the related wikipedia article may prove to be helpful?

Comment: I'd guess that their height is the average value of the function in that region? But without the article, I couldn't say more

Comment: This is the basis of integration à la Lebesgue: each color collects all the abscissas whose images are between two given limits $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ and the height of each rectangle of a given color is always the same arbitrary value between  $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$. The sum of the areas approximates the integral of the function. A misleading point is that the abscissas regions are not always finite unions of intervals, but the rough idea is correct. In Riemann integration, one would start with a decomposition of the horizontal axis into small intervals, not of the vertical axis.

Comment: @Did: Thanks for the explanation. It is now becoming clear to me.